# Logcat goes crazy on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat, android-debug

Since version 1.2.2 of Android Stduio, LogCat doesnt appear to be able to only filter the output messages of my app. Instead, it filters all my device messages.

I have Log level "Debug" and "Show only selected application" enabled.

Here's a screenshot of my LogCat: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8avs.jpg

Comment: click the green arrow to restart the logcat and see if it helps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you see log lines of the whole device.

On the right top side of logcat you see: "Show only selected application". For some reason this does not do what you expect it to do. What I always do is filter on package name.

1. Open the dropdown menu that says "Show only selected application"
2. Select "Edit Filter Configuration"
3. Enter the Package Name
4. Press OK

From this point on you will only see logging of your package.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, very detailed and straightforward.